# Inline code button doesn't work with existing backticks

Tags: bug, user-interface, editor

When I write some text, select it, and press the "code sample" button, it surrounds the selected text with single backticks. This is not sufficient to turn the text into a code sample in the case where the text itself contains backticks.

For example, if I write:

> [...] SELECT `foo` from `bar` [...]

select the text, and press Ctrl+K, it produces:

> [...] `SELECT `foo` from `bar [...]

where what I really want is:

> [...] `` SELECT `foo` from `bar` `` [...]

The correct behaviour, in my opinion, would be to count the longest contiguous sequence of backticks in the selected text, and insert a sequence one longer at the beginning and end (separated by a space to cater for the case where the text begins or ends with a backtick itself). If anyone has any examples where that would not produce the desired result, please point them out.

(It seems like the current code sample button acts as a toggle, removing backticks if present. I think this behaviour is counterintuitive in general and should probably be dropped. At the least, it should ensure there are backticks on *both* ends of the selected text before dropping either of them).

To clarify, I am saying that on input like the above, the code sample button behaves incorrectly (hence the bug tag). I already know how to escape the backticks properly, but the editor does not, and should be taught.

Comment: @hammar where do you see anything about an escape button in the editor?

Comment: Notice that I include a description of how to escape the backticks in my question, so that's pretty clearly not what I'm asking for. I've added some clarifying remarks.